# How do I show a plot of Random.gammavariate distribution?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, scipy, distribution

I am a little confused at all the different distribution functions out there (i.e. numpy, scipy, matploglib.mlab, and random)

I am trying to get a sampling of gamma distribution numbers to use for my program and also plot out the distribution being used as well.

So far I am doing:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import scipy.special as sps
import numpy as np

k = 2.0
theta = 2.0
random.gammavariate(k, theta) # this gives me results of the gamma distribution

# but unfortunately, this doesn't work
# plt.plot(random.gammavariate(k, theta))
# plt.show()

# but this works somehow even if I don't specify 
# what bins and y is - just copied from a https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.gamma.html
# and seems to work
s = np.random.gamma(k, theta, 1000)
plt.plot(bins, y, linewidth=2, color='r')
```

Any help for explaining this to me is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"...and also plot out the distribution being used as well."*  Do you want to plot the histogram of the random sample, or do you want to plot the PDF (or CDF) of the underlying distribution from which the sample was drawn (such as the plots shown at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to plot a curve (or scatter) of 1 dimensional data.
You can show the distribution by plotting the histogram:

```
plt.hist(np.random.gamma(k, theta,100 ))
```

Note the 1000 will give you 1000 points.
if you want to extract informations from the histogram like the bins:

```
 count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(np.random.gamma(k, theta, 100))
```

then you can plot with `plt.plot` that takes a 2D as input:

```
plt.plot(bins, y)
```

where y is given by:

```
import scipy.special as sps
import numpy as np
y = bins**(k-1)*(np.exp(-bins/theta) /(sps.gamma(k)*theta**k))
```

which is the gamma function.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your response.  I am unsure of what to put in `plt.plot()` after running the `plt.hist()`.

Comment: `plt.hist` will draw the bins. no need to do `plt.plot` afterwards.

Comment: exact, `plt.plot` will draw the corresponding distribution as a traditionnal _line plot_ based on the bins of your distribution.

Comment: but that's misleading. you should be computing a KDE if you want that.

Comment: I just refer to the scipy function and try to explain it..but you are right thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I am getting an error on `plt.hist(random.gammavariate(k, theta, 1000))`.  It says: `TypeError: gammavariate() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given.`  `random.gammavariate` takes two arguments but `numpy.random.gamma` takes three, the last of which is the number of samples drawn.  How do I draw samples from `random.gammavariate`?

Comment: to have for example 100 random realisation you can do: `sample =
 [random.gammavariate(a,b) for i in range(100)]`